# Ubuntu freezing very frequently

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu today and am having a problem where the entire GUI locks up after ~4 minutes, or upon certain actions like using the search bar or interfacing with the shutdown menu. I am very new to Linux and so I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing, but I tested against some of the forum questions I could understand regarding this issue. I know the problem is not the fans, because when I boot up Ubuntu I can see the fans running and feel the air coming out of my PC. I understand rolling back the kernel solved it for some people, but because I  just installed today I don't have a kernel to rollback to that is not possible. Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

I'm dual booting with Windows 10 (an upgrade from windows 7, so it has legacy BIOS, but I do have ASrock EUIF, but I installed in BIOS) my graphics card is a GTX 660 and an Intel 1-5 series processor. My Windows is 64-bit. If there's any more info you need about my hardware please let me know.

Comment: Do you have the GPU drivers for Nvidia ? If not open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346-updates` and reboot, is it working now ?

Comment: @markkirby do drivers I install on windows carry over to Ubuntu, or do I need to install them specifically on ubuntu.

Comment: This really sounds like a GPU issue. Both the dash (Ubuntu Unity search screen) and the shutdown dialog use alpha (transparency) that the graphics card usually renders. Having a driver for hardware installed in Windows does nothing for the Ubuntu install; it needs its own driver.

Comment: No they don't carry over, it is a completely different OS, the command I gave you will install the best driver for you card

Comment: @markkirby That seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If I write this as an answer please accept it with the check mark on the left to say thanks and show other users this was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by a lack of Nvidia GPU drivers.

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346-updates
```

This will install the best driver for your GTX660.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an older version of Ubuntu on this machine?  It might be that 15.10 is an ill fit (as you said, rolling back solves the issue for other affected users).

Maybe the LTS version would work better for you?

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.3/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: If you are not torrent capable, use this link instead for the 64 bit LTS -- http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.3/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: I tried to install that version, but when I did got no option to install it alongside windows. I decided to try 15.10 to see if it would give me said option and it did. Assuming I did try to install the LTS version, would i just overwrite the current version?

Comment: @Jurad215 This would really be a last resort, there is not much difference between the two versions, where your computers performance is concerned.

Comment: Then there's your answer, if there is insigificant performance difference between the 15.10 and the LTS, then overwrite the 15.10 with the LTS and see if the LTS version works better for you, given the 15.10 is of no use to you right now.

Comment: "if there is insigificant performance difference between the 15.10 and the LTS, then overwrite the 15.10 with the LTS" Reinstalling the OS should be a last resort in almost any circumstance, it is first an inconvenience for most and second may cause more issues than it fixes for new users, to illustrate my point, this was fixed with a single line of code. It is not that 15.10 is `not working for them` it is user error due to inexperience. Don't jump right on the `reinstall` answer, most questions here can easily be fixed like this.

Comment: Fair enough.  In my own defense, however, I had answered in the manner I had because it was pointed out regressing to an earlier kernel was known to solve the issue.  Reinstalling the LTS version would likely cause this to happen, and is easier to walk an inexperienced user through.  Path of least resistance.  Since a single line of code could fix this, I'm glad you were able to provide that (much more efficient) answer.